# Why is my Xamarin app not returning data from Azure if data exists before the Easy Table api is created?

Tags: sqlite, azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have noticed something strange with Azure and my Xamarin Forms app.  Please bear with me as I explain the situation and perhaps someone can shed some like on it for me.

My app uses a mobile service to access my tables API in Azure.  It doesn't always work however.

- Scenario A) If I create a table in my Azure database, then create the Easy Table API via the portal and then add the datait works without any problems and my app returns the data and everyone is happy.
- Scenario B) If I already have a table (which is the more likely situation) and then create the Easy Table API the app returns nothing.

Scenario B is where I'm at just now, so to ensure the API was working I tested it using Postman.  It returned an empty array, closer investigation showed that my table had the additional columns Easy Tables adds (`deleted`, `version`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`) but `deleted` was null.  I set them all to `false` and Postman then could see all the data, great I thought that's it sorted.  When I ran my app again in the simulator it still wasn't returning anything and I simply cannot get it to work.

What am I doing wrong here and why is the app still not returning the data (even though postman can see it) is there an additional step I need to go through? Can you not use existing data?

Comment: You are using the Azure Mobile Client SDK in your Xamarin app, right?

Comment: Yes I am @Malte I didn't want to post all the code up for the app itself as right now I'm trying to understand the Easy Table side of things.  If I create a table, then create the api and then add my data the app returns everything without a problem.

Comment: I was facing the same issue, when I updated the deleted column it solved to me!
Do you have any error message? How are you binding your data? Share the code retrieving from azure, updating the observablecollection and the view binding...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out after much confusion the reason for the lack of data was because my index column was not caled 'id' but rather 'idx_index' having now changed this it works fine.  It does mean a lot of work for me now to go and change my database column names but at least it's working :)